# How to Snapshot Region with Apache Geode and use Spring Data GemFire Repositories?

Tags: spring, apache, spring-data, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I am trying to do the below use case and I am unable to find any explanation about how to do it with Apache Geode.

For example:

I have an Apache Geode Region called A (1000 records) that has the SD *Repository* "crudRepoA".

During run-time I want to snapshot this Region to another Region called A1 (1000 records) and use a similar CRUD *Repository* that I have defined on Region A.

Is live Snapshot possible with an out-of-the-box feature of Apache Geode?

Is it possible to use the "crudRepoA" on this newly created Region?

Is there a way to create a new "crudRepoA1" (identical to "crudRepoA") on the fly and run my queries on this newly created Region?

Answer (score 0):

> *Is live Snapshot possible with an out of the box feature of Apache Geode?*

Yes.  You can use *Apache Geode's* [Cache/Region Snapshot Service](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/12/managing/cache_snapshots/chapter_overview.html) (possibly, worth a look anyway).  This is also well [supported](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/2.0.0.RC2/reference/html/#bootstrap:snapshot) by *Spring Data Geode*.

> *Is it possible to use the crudRepoA on this newly created region ?*

Well, not exactly, so...

> *Is there a way to create a new crudRepoA1 (identical to crudRepoA) on the fly and run my queries on this newly created Region?*

Yes.

You can do the following...

```
@Region("A")
class DomainTypeForRegionA { 
  @Id Long id;
  ...
}

interface RegionARepository extends GemfireRepository<DomainTypeForRegionA, Long> { ... }

@Region("A1")
interface RegionA1Repository extends RegionARepository { ... }
```

Sometime ago (`1.4.0.M1`) I added [support for annotating the application (GemFire) `Repository` interface (with `@Region`)](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SGF-261) instead/also, which overrides the *Region* in which the data for the application domain object type (defined by the `@Region` annotation on the domain object type itself, e.g. as shown above with `DomainTypeForRegionA`) is persisted or accessed.

Read the entire section [Entity Mapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.entities) in the SDG *Reference Guide*.

Hope this helps!

-John